# Triangle above note, with a dot in it

Tags: notation, fermata

What does the symbol *before* the fermata mean?

[image: Music staff with a three notes. The first note has nothing above it, the second has an inverted "v" symbol with a dot in the centre above it, and the third has a fermata above it.]

I found this symbol in [this publication](https://web.archive.org/web/20141114095757/https://silasvh.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/ludovico-einaudi-nuvole-bianche-bewerkt-door-joel-biffin.pdf) of Ludovico Einaudi's *Nuvole Bianche*, bar 98 and bar 101.

Comment: Both are written by composers who can't be bothered to state just how long they want a note to be held for. The former is shorter.

Comment: @Tim, yeah, it seems kind of pointless to specify a "shorter" or "longer" fermata, since all fermatas mean "get your nose out of your music and look up at the conductor for how long this note should last!"

Comment: @NH. I think the reason to have different "length" fermatas is for the *conductor* to have more information for deciding how long they will conduct the note length. I suppose you could copy out the parts with semicircular fermatas and leave the funny shapes on the conductor's score alone, but seems like an unnecessary step for the music copyist/software to take when there's no harm in having the symbols match between full score and parts.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's still a fermata and is typically referred to as *triangle fermata*. It's shorter than a typical fermata, but holds the same idea of prolonging the note longer than the value written. There's another variant of the fermata referred to as a square fermata that you hold longer than a typical fermata. You can see them all in the [Dolmetsch musical symbols dictionary](http://www.dolmetsch.com/musicalsymbols.htm).

Comment: It should be noted that while the fermata is commonplace, and square fermatas are somewhat frequent in modern scores, the triangle fermata is **really, really** rare. I've been using sheet music for decades, and I've never encountered a single one, ever.

Answer (score 6):

It is just a "shorter" fermata. Not official notation (actually, what is *official*) but modern composers used different shapes of fermatas to indicate different lengths. Most notably Poulenc.

Still, it remains subjective. Fermatas are never a precise alteration.

Answer (score 2):

It's a modern version of a fermata. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermata.

Some composers use these to represent differing lengths of pauses.